# How do I reset the Python interpreter's terminal width?

Tags: command-line, gnome, python

When I start python in a new 14.04 LTS gnome-terminal it is 80 character wide:

```
$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.popen('stty size', 'r').read()
'24 80\n'
```

When I resize the gnome-terminal the new size is reported:

```
>>> os.popen('stty size', 'r').read()
'23 170\n'
```

However, the input python prompt does not see the resizing and begins to overwrite the beginning of the line when I write long lines:

```
nm> 1234567890qwertyuiopåasdfghjklæøzxcvbnm1234567890qwertyuiopåasdfghjklæøzxcvb
```

Here 'nm' is wrapped.

A reset from the menu of the gnome-terminal does not help. Is there a way to inform the python interpreter that the window is resized?

Comment: Does IPython or python3 suffer from this?

Comment: Yes. Ipython and python3 also have the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Python that has appeared since readline version 6.3 was released. Ubuntu 14.04 has libreadline6 version 6.3-4ubuntu2, so 14.04 and all later Ubuntu releases are affected.

The bug has been fixed in Python, but the fix is not yet in any official release. Refer to the upstream bug report [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue23735).

The latest releases as of the time of this writing are 2.7.11 and 3.5.1, so the next releases 2.7.12, 3.5.2, and 3.6.0 should be fixed.